# Custom Post Type slug same as page name

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, custom-post-type-archives

I have two pages named News and Events. I created two custom post types with slug names as news and events and it worked just fine. However, when I try to create a CPT with a slug 'products' , Custom Post Type UI Complains with an error: `Please choose a different post type name. products matches an existing page slug, which can cause conflicts.` Why is this the case when events and news worked fine?

**My templates for news are:**
news.php(used as page template)
archive-news.php
single-news.php

**My templates for events are:**
events.php (used as page template)
archive-events.php
single-event.php

**templates for product are:**
products.php(used as page template)
archive-products.php
single-product

I am using the Custom Post Type UI Plugin. If thats valuable to know or not. My post type for news is as follows(events is the exact same).

```
add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_cpts_news' );
function cptui_register_my_cpts_news() {
    $labels = array(
        "name" => __( 'News', '' ),
        "singular_name" => __( 'News', '' ),
        "menu_name" => __( 'My News', '' ),
        "all_items" => __( 'All News', '' ),
        "add_new" => __( 'Add News', '' ),
        "add_new_item" => __( 'Add New News', '' ),
        "edit_item" => __( 'Edit News', '' ),
        "new_item" => __( 'New News', '' ),
        "view_item" => __( 'View News', '' ),
        "search_items" => __( 'Search News', '' ),
        "not_found" => __( 'No News Found', '' ),
        "not_found_in_trash" => __( 'No News Found in Trash', '' ),
        "parent_item_colon" => __( 'Parent News:', '' ),
        "featured_image" => __( 'Featured image for this news', '' ),
        "set_featured_image" => __( 'Set featured image for this news', '' ),
        "remove_featured_image" => __( 'Remove featured image for this news', '' ),
        "use_featured_image" => __( 'Use as featured image for this news', '' ),
        "archives" => __( 'News Archives', '' ),
        "insert_into_item" => __( 'Insert into news', '' ),
        "uploaded_to_this_item" => __( 'Uploaded to this news', '' ),
        "filter_items_list" => __( 'Filter news lists', '' ),
        "items_list_navigation" => __( 'News list navigation', '' ),
        "items_list" => __( 'News list', '' ),
        "parent_item_colon" => __( 'Parent News:', '' ),
        );

    $args = array(
        "label" => __( 'News', '' ),
        "labels" => $labels,
        "description" => "query latest news",
        "public" => true,
        "publicly_queryable" => true,
        "show_ui" => true,
        "show_in_rest" => false,
        "rest_base" => "",
        "has_archive" => true,
        "show_in_menu" => true,
                "exclude_from_search" => false,
        "capability_type" => "post",
        "map_meta_cap" => true,
        "hierarchical" => false,
        "rewrite" => array( "slug" => "news", "with_front" => true ),
        "query_var" => true,

        "supports" => array( "title" ),     
        "taxonomies" => array( "category" ),
            );
    register_post_type( "news", $args );

// End of cptui_register_my_cpts_news()
}
```

With this current setup, when I visit the news link on my page, i am present with all the news posts and when i click on a specific post i am directed to the single post. it works great. The url is `www.example.com/news (list of all news posts)` and `www.example.com/news/specific-post-title (single post)`. This is the same behaviour I want for the products yet I am not able to add a CPT for it. I have tried flushing permalinks with no success. What gives?

Comment: Can you expand on "it complains?" What complains?  Is this a PHP error, a WP admin error message, a white screen, a partially rendered front end page...?

Comment: @AndyMacaulay-Brook changed post with correct error, have a look. thanks!

Comment: If it's an error from a third party plugin you'd be better off using their support channels.